# Is it possible to build a Google maps url from a lat/lng position to a place id?

Tags: google-maps

I can use this to get directions between 2 lat/lngs:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=0,0&daddr=50,40
```

And I can use this to view a particular place by place id:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:PLACE_ID_HERE
```

Is it possible to do somethig similar to this?

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=0,0&daddr=PLACE_ID_HERE
```

I want to get the directions from any lat/long position to a particular Google place

Comment: I don't see Google Maps giving you a specific place ID. It uses `https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/PlaceName/` but then followed by a long `data` parameter. However I see you can use `https://www.google.com.ar/maps/dir/lat,long/PlaceName+City+State+Country` (as built by Google), or also `https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=lat,long&daddr=PlaceName+City+State+Country`.

Comment: I was able to find that place_id you mention, which is returned by their API. I don't see how it can be used directly with these urls. If you open your second url, it will convert to the long version from my comment above, and that can be used to get directions. If you are using their API, maybe you need another endpoint to get the *long* ID string instead.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? You are essentially trying to use a website and this is not considered a *programming question*. Further to that, it's all explained in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action).

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks, that link is really helpful. This relates to programming only in that my goal is to construct this url to place in an `href` - it allows my application users to open  google directions in a new tab based on information we had already retrieved from the Places API

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [useful link posted my Mr Upsidedown](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) (its the docs for Google Maps URLs specifically, rather than places/maps API), I found that this is possible by constructing the url like this

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=51.315903303198624,-0.5612461159895105&destination=51.5007293621435, -0.1246254894957886&destination_place_id=ChIJ2dGMjMMEdkgRqVqkuXQkj7c
```

So we need these params in order to achieve it:

```
origin (lat/lng)
destination (lat/lng)
destination_place_id (placeId)
```

Following the url above will show directions between the 2 co-ordinates, but will also indicate the actual place we are travelling to (Big Ben), where as excluding the `destination_place_id` will just try and show the area being travelled to (e.g. Westminster).